# Однозначность прочтения

Tags: пунктуация, смысл

Друзья!
В инструкции организации есть такая фраза:

«Пропуск передается работнику охраны в руки, при необходимости, по временному пропуску, также могут быть затребованы документы, удостоверяющие личность».

Возможно ли отнести фразу «при необходимости»  к «пропуск передается работнику охраны в руки»? Если «при необходимости» относится к первой части предложения, то передавать пропуск в руки работнику охраны нужно «при необходимости», если ко второй части, то пропуск в руки работнику охраны передавать обязательно, но фраза «при необходимости» имеет избыточный смысл. Прошу специалистов разъяснить.

Comment: Точку поставьте и не надо ничего разъяснять или точку с запятой.

Comment: В том то и проблема, что предложение читается не однозначно. Каждый трактует в свою пользу. Людей могут наказать. Хотелось бы разобраться.

Comment: Потому что составлено неграмотно и проблему можно решить, составив текст грамотно - поставив точку. Накажите тех, кто составлял либо пусть разъясняют, что имеют ввиду. Законы тоже имеют различные трактовки и к ним периодически выходят комментарии и разъяснения. Либо готовьтесь к худшему варианту, когда "при необходимости" относится ко второй части. Но также очевидно, что к первой части приписка "при необходимости" смысла не несет. Так что только 2: у вас могут быть также затребованы дополнительные документы, а не только пропуск, в подлинности которого охранник имеет право удостовериться

Comment: "По временному пропуску" не нужно выделять запятыми.

Comment: @Буратино «Но также очевидно, что к первой части приписка "при необходимости" смысла не несет. », для пример если работник нарушил или сотрудник охраны не может разобрать надпись на пропуске. Или притянуто за уши?

Comment: @Илья да это понятно, но зачем для этого приписку делать, очевидно, что охранник может удостовериться и должен удостовериться в подлинности пропуска, так как это именно тот документ который существует для охраны, а если он его в руки не может брать, то нафиг такой документ нужен.